# latex2html: cannot use mathematical formulas

Tags: math-mode, latex2html

I use `latex2html` to have my document in `HTML` format.

I have a problem with mathematical formulas. I include the following packages:

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

And when I write something like

```
$A_{x}$
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
\Delta =\sum_{i=1}^N w_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2 .
\end{equation}
```

I get compilation error.

Could anyone give me advice how to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume there must be other errors: If I pack your example into some minimal document, `latex2html` works out of the box

Comment: I also use a simple file.
However, I get non informative error: 
'\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Maybe I heve to configure something, some pathes etc. But I have not idea what should I change.

Comment: Do you have `latex2html` installed at all? At least under Linux/Unix `latex2html` actually is a `perl` script

Comment: It seems to me that I have full install.
I use it under Windows.
I also have installed perl/ghostscript and NETPBM